# Nginx increased response time after redirecting naked domains

Tags: performance, nginx

I've experienced this strange increase in endpoint latency after redirecting naked domains to their www. counterpart. I eventually rolled back.

[image]

(the different lines are different locations that the endpoint is tested from)

The change in the nginx.conf consisted in creating the following lines for each hosted domain (6 domains in total):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 http://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com;

    root /usr/share/nginx/www;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  log_format;

    location = /favicon.ico {
        root /home/www/example;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
        root /home/www/example;
    }

    location /static {
        root /home/www/example;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
    }
}
```

While before I had something like:

```
server {    
    listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
    #listen   [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

    root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    #index index.html index.htm;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    # server_name  localhost;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  log_format;

    location = /favicon.ico {
            root /home/www/example;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
            root /home/www/example;
    }

    location /static {
            root /home/www/example;
    }

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
            proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
            proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
    }
}
```

Any ideas why this is happening? Thanks!

Comment: You measure site performance from outside world, I assume.
If you didn't change site's code to request resources from www.* version this may be due to additional roundtrips to get content. Eg. get site.com/js/app.js -> redirect to www.site.com/js/app.js

Comment: Yes, it's measured from outside the "local" network, from various locations around the world. It would be due to extra round trips, although from the logs I see that the monitoring agent doesn't fetch static files, only the endpoint I tell it.

Comment: Just wondering, did you update DNS to add an "A" for www and then redirect to www? (I'm asking about DNS propagation delay)

Comment: Also, the redirect will use additional connections while redirecting (includes proxies and a file limit) http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#worker_connections . You may also have an interaction as described here (nginx listen queue, SPI firewall dropping SYNs, socket limits): http://serverfault.com/a/419960/246220 . The asker is using "apache bench" to get some better statistics.

Comment: By the way, try such config for redirect.
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    rewrite ^(.*)$ $scheme://www.example.com$1 permanent;
}